# Out of bound exception when splitting Strings java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split this string so that I can assign each value to its own variable. But I cant seem to get it to not appear as a out of bound exception. When I print it with just the lineSplit1[0] it's fine, the problem starts when I include the lineSplit1[1]. Here is one of the lines i'm trying to split from the text file "Friday¬7/4/2017¬12:50¬13:50¬Test¬"

Comment: Did you debug it? Are you sure `lineSplit` contains 2 elements (don't assume)?

Comment: @Carcigenticate debuggint it didnt help, and when printing lineSplit1[0] it prints Friday. All the suggestions for finding and assigning the next variable suggest that I did it correctly, which is why I dont understand the exception.

Comment: Could you show us the contents of `repeatData.txt` file?

Comment: Print the line first.

Comment: As a debugging exercise, print `lineSplit1.length` right after creating the array.

Comment: @Jezor The line included is the only line in the text file.

Comment: You checked `lineSplit1[0]` but not `lineSplit1[1]`?

Comment: @Jezor printing the length gives me first a length of 1 and immediately after 5, 5 is the expected length

Comment: @Carcigenicate I cant check lineSplit1[1] because that is what causes the out of bound exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem you're getting is this: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
what does it mean? that you're trying to get a position form your array that does not exist (in your example lineSplit1[1]), why would happen this? maybe your file sometimes does not contain the character "¬" two or more times.

For example look at this

```
String string = "Fridays7/4/2017d12:50d13:50dTestd";
          String[] lineSplit1 = string.split("¬");
          for(String s: lineSplit1){
              System.out.println(s);
              System.out.println(lineSplit1.length);
              String day1 = lineSplit1[0];
                String date1 = lineSplit1[1];
                System.out.println(day1+""+date1);
          }
    }
```

I have the same problem as you but you could use this:

```
String string = "Fridays7/4/2017d12:50d13:50dTestd";
  String[] lineSplit1 = string.split("¬");
  for(String s: lineSplit1){
      System.out.println(s);
      String day1 = lineSplit1[0];
      String date1 = null;
      if(lineSplit1.length>1)
       date1= lineSplit1[1];
      else
          date1="thisisANullDate";
        System.out.println(day1+""+date1);
  }
```

}

Now i told my program, check my array lenght is > 1 if it is correct i know i have the date 1 if it not true well i could do whatever i want, so:

1.- Check that all the lines you have are equal (when you split is because you know that there always be the same patron)
2.- if someimes this does not happen, then use a validator as me.

Hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   String testStr="Friday¬7/4/2017¬12:50¬13:50¬Test¬";                
   String[] lineSplit1 = testStr.split("¬");
   if (lineSplit1.length>1){
       System.out.println("Number of words: "+lineSplit1.length); // print using index=1
       System.out.println(lineSplit1[1]);
   }
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(testStr);

   while(scanner.hasNext()){                      
     System.out.println(scanner.next());                     
   }
   scanner.close();
}
```